# Using ethernet, how do I navigate to a page on my local server

Tags: ethernet

I want to access the following page on my local using my Arduino with ethernet shield"  192.168.1.2/zombie/arduino.php.  My arduino is conencted to a PC through a router. The system keeps timing out

I am using the following code:

```
#include <Ethernet.h>
#include <SPI.h>


byte mac[] = { 0xDE, 0xAD, 0xBE, 0xEF, 0xFE, 0xED };
byte ip[] = { 192,168,1,3 };
char server[] = "192.168.1.2/zombie/arduino.php";

EthernetClient client;

void setup()
{
  Ethernet.begin(mac, ip);
  Serial.begin(9600);

  delay(1000);

  Serial.println("connecting...");

  int res = client.connect(server, 80);

  Serial.println(res);

  if (res) {
    Serial.println("connected");
    client.println();
  } else {
    Serial.println("connection failed");
  }
}

void loop()
{
  if (client.available()) {
    char c = client.read();
    Serial.println("data:");
    Serial.println(c);
  }else{
    Serial.println("NA");
  }

  if (!client.connected()) {
    Serial.println();
    Serial.println("disconnecting.");
    client.stop();
    for(;;)
      ;
  }
}
```

Comment: "localhost" means the loopback interface (ie, 127.0.0.1), and so **by definition** cannot be accessed from any other system.  You have a *local* server (presumably on the same subnet as your Arduino), not a "localhost" one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I discovered the answer after some testing.

The server var:

```
char server[] = "192.168.1.2/zombie/arduino.php";
```

should only contain the ip address.  So it should look like this:

```
byte server[] = { 192,168,1,2 };
```

The additional URL elements should be added using:

```
client.println("GET /zombie/arduino.php");
```

after a connection has been established

The final code should look like this:

```
#include <Ethernet.h>
#include <SPI.h>


byte mac[] = { 0xDE, 0xAD, 0xBE, 0xEF, 0xFE, 0xED };
byte ip[] = { 192,168,1,3 };
byte server[] = { 192,168,1,2 };

EthernetClient client;

void setup()
{
  Ethernet.begin(mac, ip);
  Serial.begin(9600);

  delay(1000);

  Serial.println("connecting...");

  int res = client.connect(server, 80);

  Serial.println(res);

  if (res) {
    Serial.println("connected");
    client.println("GET /zombie/arduino.php");
    client.println();
  } else {
    Serial.println("connection failed");
  }
}

void loop()
{
  if (client.available()) {
    char c = client.read();
    Serial.println("data:");
    Serial.println(c);
  }else{
    Serial.println("NA");
  }

  if (!client.connected()) {
    Serial.println();
    Serial.println("disconnecting.");
    client.stop();
    for(;;)
      ;
  }
}
```